# PHP Calendar table

Tags: php, calendar

Hi Im trying to make a calendar table that displays the months in a year and days in a week.

I am able to make one for this month(Nov 2016). Now I want to loop it through out the year and for coming years.

Can someone help me?

```
<?php
/* Set the default timezone */
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Hong_Kong");

/* Set the date */
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));

$day = date('d', $date);
$month = date('m', $date);
$year = date('Y', $date);

// $nextyear = strtotime('+1 month', $date);

$firstDay = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year);
$title = strftime('%B', $firstDay);
$dayOfWeek = date('D', $firstDay);
$daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);
/* Get the name of the week days */
$timestamp = strtotime('next Sunday');
$weekDays = array();



for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++) {
    $weekDays[] = strftime('%a', $timestamp);
    $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
}
$blank = date('w', strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01"));
?>




<table class='table table-bordered' style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="32" class="text-center"> <?php echo $title ?> <?php echo $year ?> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($weekDays as $key => $weekDay) : ?>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $weekDay ?></td>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php for($i = 0; $i < $blank; $i++): ?>
            <td></td>
        <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++): ?>
            <?php if($day == $i): ?>
                <td><strong><?php echo $i ?></strong></td>
            <?php else: ?>
                <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(($i + $blank) % 32 == 0): ?>
                </tr><tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php for($i = 0; ($i + $blank + $daysInMonth) % 32 != 0; $i++): ?>
            <td></td>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This is painful! Take a look at client side javascript libraries for that instead. They are there, ready to be used, offer a wide scale of features, options and themes.

Comment: I already checked some of those but what I need is just a simple calendar table that displays a full month horinzontically not like the typical calendar table

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. So you say you have a month and now want to loop over months? Ok, so what is the issue? Why can't you simply loop? You need some catalog anyway that codes the number of days per month.

Comment: I dont know how to do the loop per month. Like if november ends it will show a new table for december

Comment: Your approach is based on the current date, that is questionable since it makes the solution inflexible. Instead you will have to wrap all that definitions in the beginning into some function that takes a date as an argument. Then you can easily implement two loops nested inside each other, the outer iterating over years, the inner over the months, and call said function to gain the required definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments above you can use two loops nested inside each other, one for the years, one for the months. That way you can execute your already given code based on different dates but the current one.

Have a look at this approach. It basically does what you are looking for, but you need to do some fine tuning for the layout:

```
<?php

define('NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS', 37);    

function renderCalenderMonth($date) {
  $day = date('d', $date);
  $month = date('m', $date);
  $year = date('Y', $date);

  $firstDay = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year);
  $title = strftime('%B', $firstDay);
  $dayOfWeek = date('D', $firstDay);
  $daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);
  /* Get the name of the week days */
  $timestamp = strtotime('next Sunday');
  $weekDays = array();

  for ($i = 0; $i < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; $i++) {
      $weekDays[] = strftime('%a', $timestamp);
      $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
  }
  $blank = date('w', strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01"));
  ?>

  <table class='table table-bordered' style="table-layout: fixed;">
      <tr>
      <th colspan="<?php echo NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS?>" class="text-center"> <?php echo $title ?> <?php echo $year ?> </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <?php foreach($weekDays as $key => $weekDay) : ?>
          <td class="text-center"><?php echo $weekDay ?></td>
      <?php endforeach ?>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <?php for($i = 0; $i < $blank; $i++): ?>
          <td></td>
      <?php endfor; ?>
      <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++): ?>
          <?php if($day == $i): ?>
          <td><strong><?php echo $i ?></strong></td>
          <?php else: ?>
          <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if(($i + $blank) % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS == 0): ?>
          </tr><tr>
          <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endfor; ?>
      <?php for($i = 0; ($i + $blank + $daysInMonth) % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS != 0; $i++): ?>
          <td></td>
      <?php endfor; ?>
      </tr>
  </table>

  <?php
}

// ===========================

/* Set the default timezone */
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Hong_Kong");

for ($iterateYear=2016; $iterateYear<2018; $iterateYear++) {
  for ($iterateMonth=1; $iterateMonth<=12; $iterateMonth++) {

    /* Set the date */
    $date = strtotime(sprintf('%s-%s-01', $iterateYear, $iterateMonth));
    renderCalenderMonth($date);

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Im currently migrating the code to laravel 5.3 Ill post my laravel 5.3 code for this. Can you help me check it? It doesnt loop

Answer (score -1):

Laravel 5.3 version of calendar code:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')->where('roles_id', '2')->get();

    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Hong_Kong");

    for ($iterateYear = 2017; $iterateYear < 2018; $iterateYear++) {
        for ($iterateMonth = 1; $iterateMonth <= 12; $iterateMonth++) {
            /* Set the date */
            $date = strtotime(sprintf('%s-%s-01', $iterateYear, $iterateMonth));
            return $this->renderCalenderMonth($date);
        }
    }

    return view('transaction.index', [
      'users' => $users
    ]);
}

public function renderCalenderMonth($date)
{
    // $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 37;

    $day = date('d', $date);
    $month = date('m', $date);
    $year = date('Y', $date);

    $firstDay = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year);
    $title = strftime('%B', $firstDay);
    $dayOfWeek = date('D', $firstDay);
    $daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);
    /* Get the name of the week days */
    $timestamp = strtotime('next Sunday');
    $weekDays = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; $i++) {
        $weekDays[] = strftime('%a', $timestamp);
        $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
    }

    $blank = date('w', strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01"));
    $divid = $title . $year;

    return view('transaction.index', [
        'date' => $date,
        'day' => $day,
        'month' => $month,
        'year' => $year,
        'firstDay' => $firstDay,
        'title' => $title,
        'dayOfWeek' => $dayOfWeek,
        'daysInMonth' => $daysInMonth,
        'timestamp' => $timestamp,
        'weekDays' => $weekDays,
        'blank' => $blank,
        'divid' => $divid,
        'NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS' => $NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS
    ]);
}
```

I'm only getting this. Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: The issue is that you `return` _inside_ each iteration. That means you jump out of that function during the _first_ iteration (return to calling scope), so that subsequent iterations are never executed. _Do not return!_ If you buffer the output, then concatenate it to some string value and return in the end.

Comment: And a general hint: it is extremely painful to exchange code this way. I suggest you put your code into some revision control system like a git or subversion repository (github is just fine). That way others can use your code and create modifications you can review and accept or deny. That is how code development gets _much_ more efficient for you.

Comment: How do I do this? "If you buffer the output, then concatenate it to some string value and return in the end." @arkascha

Comment: Please start reading the documentations... For output buffering start here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php It allows you to "capture" content you output by means of `echo` or the like (for example html markup) and get them inside a string variable. You then can do with it what you want. For example you can have a buffer variable and concatenate the captured month output from each iteration. In the end you have a single variable holding the full html markup for all months and years which you can then `return` or `echo`.